# gradlew gatlingRun doesn't run any test

Tags: scala, performance, gradle, load, gatling

I am trying to perform a load testing with gradle-gattling, below are my `build.gradle` and my `BasicSimulation.scala`

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.lkishalmi.gatling" version "3.0.2"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'scala'
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8'
}

gatling {
    simulations = {
        include "**/predictors/*.scala"
    }
}

gatlingRun {
    systemProperties 'endpoint': "${endpoint}"
}
```

I put the BasicSimulation.scala in the `src/gatling/predictors` folder.

```
package predictors

import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
class BasicSimulation extends Simulation {
  val httpConf = http.baseURL("http://localhost:8000/")
  val scn = scenario("Basic Simulation")
    .exec(http("request_1")
      .get("api/chemocare/gatling/"))
    .pause(5)
  setUp(
    scn.inject(atOnceUsers(80))
  ).protocols(httpConf)
}
```

I set up my rest-api and test it with postman. It works fine. 
However, when I run `gradlew gatlingRun`, it seems like none of the test is executed and no report is generated. I got this message instead:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

How do I execute and register the test?

Comment: Did you try to put your file into `src/gatling/simulations` with a closure that includes every file with extension `.scala`?

Comment: yes, I added my file to several folders, I've also tried to include those folder in my build.gradle. But no luck so far.

Comment: The setup from your current example cannot work, because the `src/gatling/simulations` is the base path and every `include` is evaluated starting from this base path.

Comment: Yep, it is now detect the simulation, though I got an error `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some simulations failed : BasicSimulation`. I can work from that.
Thanks

Comment: The gardle plugin is now officially part of Gatling: https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/gradle_plugin. The new default location for simulations is now `src/gatling/scala` and  `src/gatling/resources`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and wanted to share my solution, as it deviates a bit from the comments.

In general it is true, that a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` without running a test, might indicate that Gatling wasn't able to find the simulations.

In my case I've been running:

```
gradle gatlingRun-MySimulation
```

What I've missed is that `xyz` in `gatlingRun-xyz` has to be a [fully qualified name](https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/gradle_plugin/#default-tasks). So the command should be

```
gradle gatlingRun-org.corp.pkge.MySimulation
```

Answer (score 1):

In local, I tried with below approach working fine for me ->

gradle clean build -> to clean build the project

./gradlew gatlingRun-com.project.sample.performance.simulations.sample.SampleBaseSimulation-> to run the single file

gradle gatlingRun-com.project.sample.performance.simulations.sample.SampleBaseSimulation-> to run the single file

gradle gatlingRun -> to run all simulations

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was getting BUILD SUCCESSFUL but test was not running.

I gave correct command (below command) to run gatling test, in fact which was working earlier, suddenly stopped working. After a bit of investigation I have got to know that build files have been replaced with old files.

**I deleted content in build folder** in gatling module and **rebuilt** the module, then the source files have been build into build folder, then the below command starts working again

```
./gradlew myproject-service-gatling:gatlingRun-com.org.myproject.StoreMyQueriesToSolrGatlingTest
```

My project structure

```
  Root_Proj

   |__ myproject-service
   
          |__ src

               |__ gatling [myproject-service-gatling]
                   
                    |__ build

                         |__ resources

                         |__ scala

               |__ main
          
                    |__ java

                    |__ resources

               |__ test

                    |__ java

                    |__ resources
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody may place simulations in the wrong package (by default IntelliJ IDEA creates `main/scala` or `main/java` source set when you are creating an empty Gradle project)

Check does your files are placed in `gatling/scala` package

And then run all simulations using `./gradlew clean gatlingRun` command

Comment: Or you might add a custom source in your grade file.

Answer (score 0):

I almost went crazy with this problem, even though this does not answer the OP  (who named the test correctly) I'm going to post it here for others. `gatlingRun` will only execute Simulations whose name end in `Simulation`. The exact syntax is documented under the [plugin configuration](https://docs.gatling.io/reference/extensions/build-tools/gradle-plugin/#plugin-configuration).

Comment: Disclaimer: Gatling creator here. Indeed, the existing behavior of our gradle plugin is pretty unexpected. The reason is that it was originally a popular community component that was ultimately contributed. As a result, it's behavior is not aligned with our other build plugins such as the maven one. We've decided to completely break the existing behavior in Gatling 3.11.0 (ETA mid April 2024) and implement one that makes more sense to us.